# Linux vm in vmware "Error loading operating system"

Tags: linux, vmware-esxi, redhat, vmware-vsphere

I have a vm I cloned from a physical server using vmwares p2v converter and after the clone the new vm wont load the os. The error I get is "Error loading operating system"

The cloned machine is a rhel 3 32bit server. I believe its esxi 5.5.

I uploaded an arch iso to the vmware storage and booted with that. When I had that started lslbk shows the 3 partitions that were converted, sda1,2 and 3. /boot , swap  and /. I was able to mount all of them and I was able to chroot into the root partition. `parted -l` shows the 3 partitions on /dev/sda. The first parition has the boot flag.

It seems like all of this is ok as far as Linux goes. I think if it was a linux issue I would at least load grub and get an error about no drives and it would drop to the rescue shell.

Im not sure if there is some vmware configuration I am missing or what I would need to check?

What seems suspicious to me is that in the bios the only detected device in primary master is the cdrom when set to auto. When i switched Virtual Device Node in the virtual hardware settings it did show up in the bios as primary slave but still would start.

Comment: RHEL 3... LOL!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This wasn't a vmware issue like I suspected. The problem was with grub. 
chroot and `grub-install /dev/sda` allowed the machine to start up.